# Does vagrant have a private_network cleanup command?

Tags: vagrant

I had a couple of VMs running yesterday.

Today I accidentally deleted some of the folders which had their Vagrant folders.

Then I connected ON and OFF to the office VPN and tried to spin up some new vagrant VMs with a private network. None of the VMs today is able to talk to the host VM by the vagrant's `private_network` command. Even the Vagrantfiles working yesterday are not working. I am using Vagrant 1.8.1

Does Vagrant have a network clean command that can just wash away older artifacts and give me a clean slate to start?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately had to do a machine restart and that fixed the problem. But it would have been good to see what was wrong.